# index number is zero and resulting "Null check operator used on a null value"

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been using fake API to sharhen my grasp over Rest API

But this line of code `NetworkImage(snapshot.data!.data![index].images![position].url.toString())),` 
is my headache can't precede since morning.
Compilation results into.

Probably happeneing because of index value in zero.
If that's the reason then what to do ?

Error is basically
The following _CastError was thrown building:
Null check operator used on a null value

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      _LastExampleScreenState.build...

Error Source is

```
FutureBuilder<ProductsModel>(
              future: getProductsApi(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Text('Loading');
                } else {
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.data!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1,
                            child: ListView.builder(
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              itemCount:
                                  snapshot.data!.data![index].images?.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                                return Container(
                                  height:
                                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25,
                                  width:
                                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    image: DecorationImage(
                                        image: NetworkImage(snapshot.data!
                                            .data![index].images![position].url
                                            .toString())),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
```

Whole Source code is here https://github.com/Jabidgithub/Flutter-Rest-API-Full-Package

Comment: why you are having `data!.data` 2x times ? can you include your snapshot response. try print/debug on `snapshot.data!.data?[index].images?[position].url` and `itemCount: snapshot.data?.data?.length,`

Comment: One data is for snapshot and the next is for Json structure.

Comment: snapshot.data!.data![index].images?.length prints null.

Comment: you aren't receiving any data, check your future method.

Comment: First it prints null and then it prints Instance of ProductsModel

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `getProductsApi()` in   your future. You call that by assigning it to a variable in initState and then use the variable as the future:

Comment: can you try calling other state like waiting, error

Comment: ...I also don't understand the data.data bit, but can't test it as I'm on my mobile.

Comment: hasError returning false and connectionState is returning done

Comment: I had called `getProductsApi()` in future in others too but none of the resulted error.